# Error downloading a file using python package requests with https

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-requests

I'm a begginer in Python and have been struggling with downloading a file using the package requests. My code works for an url with http, but not for https. The code is the following:

```
import requests
url = 'https://firms.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/active_fire/shapes/zips/Central_America_24h.zip'

print "downloading with requests"
r = requests.get(url)
with open("Central_America_24h.zip", "wb") as code:
    code.write(r.content)
```

I get the following errors:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 90
    InsecurePlatformWarning
InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lmixco\Downloads\descarga.py", line 8, in <module>
    r = requests.get(url)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 68, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 594, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 196, in resolve_redirects
    **adapter_kwargs
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 431, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:503: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
```

I have been looking for a solution, but have not found anything. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you follow the instructions? InsecurePlatformWarning: A true SSLContext object is not available. This prevents urllib3 from configuring SSL appropriately and may cause certain SSL connections to fail. For more information, see https://urllib3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/security.html#insecureplatformwarning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to install a package , use this

```
pip install requests[security]
```

for debain / ubuntu , install this before installing above package

```
apt-get install python-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried to install the package, but I got the following message: C:\>pip install requests[security]
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): requests[security] in
c:\python27\arcgis10.1\lib\site-packages
  requests 2.6.2 does not provide the extra 'security' .  I'll keep trying.

Comment: upgrade to python 3+ , mostly it will solve the issue and if u cant upgrade the use this command to install latest python SSL modules 

   :    pip install --upgrade ndg-httpsclient

Comment: @Ernesto561 which version of python are u using ?

Comment: I was using python 2.7.2. I have upgraded to python 2.7.9 and everything is working fine now. I need to use python 2.7.x. Thanks.

Comment: Installing the latest python SSL modules did the job as well. Thank you very much.

Comment: Working on an enterprise I tend to browse this site as a viewer. That hint on `pip install --upgrade ndg-httpsclient` is the type of thing that makes one even login in stackoverflow just to push an upvote! thousands of kudos @polasairam !